# How to solve a polynomial congruence when you can't factor?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

I'm trying to find the values that are solutions of the following congruence $$x^3 +4x^2+14x+9 = 0 \mod 19$$  I tried to factor it but couldn't. Factoring is the only way I know.

Comment: Another way would be to try each of the $19$ possible values for $x$ ...

Comment: In this case, if you begin to try all possible values for $x$, you will quickly find a root $a$ and then you can factor using Euclidean division by $x-a$.

Comment: Please visit [this site](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to format your questions with MathJax, in order to make your question more readable.

Answer (score 1):

For N that small you can simply test all values, it so happens that $(x-3)$ is a factor ($3^3+4*3^2+14*3+9 = 8+17+4+9 = 0$). After that, $x^3+4x^2+14x+9 = (x-3)(x^2+7x+16)=(x-3)(x-5)(x-7)$.